# IP address pointing to the router instead of the domain

Tags: ip-address, router

I set up a domain and I set the IP address to the IP of my server through whatismyipaddress.com. When I send a request to that domain, it connects me to the router instead of the computer. Does that mean I have to change the router settings so that it connects to the server when requested?
Thanks

Comment: This question isn't about programming and is better suited on one of the other stackexchange networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should to set up the ports forwarding on your router to be able to access desired services from internet (i.e., to access an web-server, TCP 80 should be forwarded).

The second — note that you can not access your services by hostname, defined at whatismyipaddess.com from the LAN behind your router, if works only for access from Internet.

If you want to do it from LAN you should use local DNS (the domain you registered should point to local IP-address of your server), or even hosts file, if you have just few computers in LAN.

Comment: Thanks. I made the port forwarding and now the browser tries to connect but then fails. Is that a problem with apache server?

Comment: Don't mix the issues. First check Apache inside the LAN. If it works as expected: check access from Internet (an, once again, you could do it ONLY via another internet connection, but not from LAN).

Answer (score 0):

You have an internal interface and an external interface on the router. The IP you get from "whatismyipaddress.com" is the ISP assigned IP that is on your external router interface. If you're trying to make it so you can get to your computer directly you would either unplug it from the router and plug it straight into your internet connection, or you would put it on something called the DMZ for demilitarized zone, which would be just as risky as plugging it straight into the Internet. Doing this is not recommended for someone who isn't sure how IP routing works.

If by domain you mean that you're going to host your own webserver and you've changed the DNS for your webserver to your own IP, then if you're using a small home router (not recommended) you would use the DMZ, otherwise if you're using a corporate enterprise level or mid-level routing your would setup something called NAT (Network Address Translation) and map certain IPs from your ISP to the server itself via the internal network on the backside of the router. This way you can limit access to whichever ports necessary (eg. Port 80 for a webserver).